# Necesito ayuda para hacer una consulta en mvc para validar que el nombre del empleado ya existe

Tags: mvc, jquery-validate

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.equipoId, "Equipo Empleado", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("equipoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.equipoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.empleadoId, "Empleado", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("empleadoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empleadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres conseguir la lista de los nombres del empleado ya existe? ¿Puedes explicar más?

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo leas con detenimiento el siguiente articulo [Validación de formularios en ASP.NET MVC - Unobtrusive Validate](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/11/12/validaci%C3%B3n-de-formularios-en-aspnet-mvc-unobtrusive-validate). Podrás ver todo lo necesario para realizar validaciones an ASP.NET MVC con jQueryValidate.